Create multiple CSV files from an single data extension
I have a scenario where lead data is stored in the SFMC data extension and sent WhatsApp campaign. Depending on the response, I have to send that data to the sales representative. For every lead, a sales representative is assigned. The task is to generate a CSV file for each sales representative and send it to the SFTP so that only that sales representative can pick up the file and communicate.
How Can I create a Multiple CSV file from a Single DE?
Note:- I know Data extract->file transfer activity but this only generates 1 file at a time. but I have a case where I have to create more than 100 files daily at a time from 1 DE.

Sorry but this sounds like an XY problem -
https://sketchplanations.com/the-xy-problem;
Why csv if the data is leads (from SFSC); why sftp; what sales rep willingly accesses an ftp? is that a secure storage? how does the sales rep then log his interactions post hoc?
This could be done using tasks, campaign members or anything else in the SFSC data model. If you NEED this very solution path, then you are looking at a script that dynamically builds automations of SQL queries, data extracts and file transfers.

@JonasLamberty I had same of the same thoughts as you outline here. I just assumed that not all SFMC environments are in a multi-cloud setup with Sales Cloud. Hence it might be reasonable to assume, a CRM system is in place, providing an API on updating status of a lead in whatever application it might reside.

very true. Also true, I think under all circumstances: ask these questions first before diving into the nitty gritty.

Thank you for the response

Could you use Automation Studio to run a daily Filter then export from that Filtered DE and send the file to the SFTP? So you'd have multiple Filters & Filtered DEs you'd use instead of the original DE.
